# Dom exception debugging with chrome developer tools in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools, domexception

I have been receiving a single dom exception all the time, when starting my debug session using chrome develper tools. This problem still persists, even with this small HTML test document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The exception  code: 12 message: "SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12"

The exception occurs in line 1904 :

```
            try {
                b.call(c.documentElement, "[test!='']:sizzle")
            } catch (f) {
                e = !0
            }
```

Any ideas? I am using chrome 19.0.1084.36

Comment: have you tried it with all of your extensions disabled? (Ctrl+shift+N)

Comment: I deactivated all the extensions and that did not help. Using your above keystroke Ctrl+shift+N chrome switched to ingocnito with the same effect.

Comment: It appears to be a way to test for a specific browser feature. Very annoying if you keep the web inspector open with "Pause on all exceptions"

Comment: Thank you Paul. So nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks for Paul Greyson's answer.

Unfortunately, his answer is in a comments and not clear for people seeking the solution.

To make it clear here is the summary:

In the bottom status bar of Chrome developer tool, there is a icon looks like a 'Pause' button, which you can toggle how the chrome will pause on exceptions by clicking it.

Answer (score 20):

[image: just Toggle this button for remove this problem]

> Just Toggle this button for remove this problem. This is common problem and everybody should know that.